# Error when I try to enter on local adress

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I try to reach the website from http://localhost:8080/Films/showAll i obtain the 404 http error. So I try to other address and from http://localhost:8080/showAll i see 406 http error.
The controller class looks like this:

```
package Films.controller;

import Films.dao.DirectorDAO;
import Films.dao.FilmDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

@RestController
// klasa odpowiada za pobieranie oraz przsył danych wykorzystywanych w DAO
public class FilmOperationController {

    ......

    // metoda zwraca listę wszystkich filmów bazie
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showAll", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Object[]> showAll() {
        return filmDao.getAllFilms();
    }

    ....
}
```

Here is pom.xml and java config file.
https://github.com/lukasz-chojn/films_database/blob/master/pom.xml
https://github.com/lukasz-chojn/films_database/blob/master/src/main/java/Films/component/Config.java

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Does the other rest endpoints work?

Comment: I created only one because I wanted to see if it would work

Comment: Are you sure that your web context root is `Films`?. You can check that (in eclipse) by right clicking on project in project explorer -> properties -> in the list on the left side at the bottom click on Web project settings, and see what is the value of Contect root. If it is something other then `Films` type that in your url instead of `Films`.

Comment: Where I can find those informations in Intelij Idea?

Comment: I am not sure for intellij. But you could try with `films_database`. So try http://localhost:8080/films_database/showAll

Comment: OK, so I have 404 http error on this address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent few hours to debug your issue. There was lot of unused dependencies and code. I refactored the code, and resolved the issue.

Here is the link to download it

https://github.com/deepakjain0812/testrepo

Please run it on your local and let me know if you see any issue.

I will delete this repo once you confirm that you are no longer facing issues with status codes like 500, 401 or 406

http://localhost:8080/showAll

Comment: Thank you for your time. I do not have any errors at the moment

Answer (score 0):

A `@RestController` is supposed to be consumed by a Rest Client, not a browser.
In order to test this kind of controller, you can use another tool like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Here is an example of how you would use your API using curl with a terminal: `curl http://localhost:8080/showAll`